# Lookup method injection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I was reading the article on `Lookup method injection` in Spring http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection.

In this, there is a statement

```
If the method is abstract, the dynamically-generated subclass implements the method. 
Otherwise, the dynamically-generated subclass overrides the concrete method defined in the original class.
```

I didn't understand the difference between these two.Can someone please explain with an example?

Answer (score 2):

```
Lookup Method DI:-

What is Lookup Method-
Here lookup method means
if a method, if it is not having any implementation or
if a method, if it is required any depedency we can consider that method as a lookup method.

for ex.
1. In case of interface

interface Test{

 public void a(); //lookup method
 public void b(); //lookup method

}

2. In case of abstract class

abstract class Test{

    abstract public void a(); //lookup method

    public void b(){

    }  
}

3. In case of concrete class

class Test{

/* if you want to override method a() then you can call this method also like lookup method */
    public void a(){
        //implementation
    }

    public void b(){
        //implementation
    }
}

Note:-if you want to provide implementation to that method you can call that method as lookup method.

By using spring you can provide implementation,
for abstract classes you can provide implementation,
for interface you can provide implementation and
in case if you don’t satisfy existing implementation from concreate class that implementation also you can override.

**Example:-**

*Required jar file
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
cglib-nodep-2.2.jar :- cglib jar will help to generate runtime proxy.

**Engine class**

package beans;

public class Engine {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

**Car interface**

package beans;

public interface Car {

    //return Engine class object
    public Engine myCarEngine();
}

**Bus abstract class**

package beans;

abstract public class Bus {

    //return Engine class object
    abstract public Engine myBusEngine();
}

**Truk concrete class**

package beans;

public class Truck {

    //if you don't satisfy this existing implementation you can override by using lookup method.
    public Engine myTrukEngine(){
        Engine e=new Engine();
        e.setName("Eicher-Truck");
        return e;
    }
}

**spring.xml**

<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"  "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>

  <!-- for car interface provide lookup method -->
    <bean id="c" class="beans.Car">
        <lookup-method name="myCarEngine" bean="e" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="e" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="name" value="swift Car Engine" />
    </bean>


  <!-- for bus abstract provide lookup method -->
    <bean id="b" class="beans.Bus">
        <lookup-method name="myBusEngine" bean="e1" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="name" value="TATA BusEngine" />
    </bean>


  <!-- for Truck concrete provide lookup method -->
    <bean id="t" class="beans.Truck">
        <lookup-method name="myTrukEngine" bean="e2" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="e2" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="name" value="BENZ Truck Engine" />
    </bean>

</beans>

**Client class**

package test;

import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import beans.Bus;
import beans.Car;
import beans.Truck;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ap= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resource/spring.xml");
        System.out.println("-----------Car----------");
        Car c=(Car)ap.getBean("c");
        System.out.println("Name of Class generated by spring at runtime="+c.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println("Engine Name="+c.myCarEngine().getName());

        System.out.println("-----------Bus----------");
        Bus b=(Bus)ap.getBean("b");
        System.out.println("Name of  Class generated by spring at runtime="+b.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println("Engine Name="+b.myBusEngine().getName());

        System.out.println("-----------Truk----------");
        Truck t=(Truck)ap.getBean("t");
        System.out.println("Name of Class generated by spring at runtime="+t.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println("Engine Name="+t.myTrukEngine().getName());

    }


}

**OutPut:-**

———–Car———-
Name of Class generated by spring at runtime=beans.Car$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$68fda491
Engine Name=swift Car Engine

———–Bus———-
Name of Class generated by spring at runtime=beans.Bus$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cfce5a7
Engine Name=TATA BusEngine

———–Truk———-
Name of Class generated by spring at runtime=beans.Truck$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$dc82ada3
Engine Name=BENZ Truck Engine

How to spring provide implementation :-
if we load spring.xml file into Ioc Container ,then Ioc container generate runtime proxy class by using cglib jar for provide implementation.
like..


//This class generate by Spring at runtime
class CarProxy extends Car{
    @Override
    public Engine myCarEngine(){

        //implementation
        return e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where Spring makes use of CGLib. That isn't important - the point is that you should understand Spring is creating a proxy object that handing that instance to your clients.

That proxy object, which Spring generates for you using CGLib, can either **implement** an abstract method, or **override** a concrete method. So it examines your class to work out if you are supplying a method that is marked abstract, or if you have supplied a method that is not marked abstract (and thus your method will be overridden).

Proxies are used across quite a few containers. They are common at runtime in the Java Enterprise world too. Where your class may be subclassed by a runtime proxy, you will find you need to supply a no-args constructor (non-public is fine) if you also want a public constructor with arguments.

Comment: Thanks..but what difference does it make if i supply an abstract or non-abstract method? any pros/cons?

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that the general concept is to not provide any implementation for lookup-method as you want to have it injected. But this leads you to a problem:
1) If you define this method as abstract in a class which already is abstract then your subclasses must implement it.
2) If you define such a method in non-abstract class you must make this class abstract then.
To avoid such forced changes it is more convenient to provide a body.

Answer (score 0):

In multi Threading Environment you have requirement like, you want inject a prototype bean in Single ton bean,but spring will return one object only for one bean when bean scope is singleton.then Prototype will  not work it will act as singleton because it was injected once by Spring IOC container.At that time we will Lookup Method Injection provided by Spring.By using Lookup Method Injection we will get  a singleton object  with injected new Prototype Object every time You call.But how it will get...? Now you will get the Answer for your question,when you configure the your prototype bean id as lookup method in you SpringBeanConfiguratipon file, Internally spring will create the Prototype$Proxy class from extending you Prototype class and it override the your lookup method. if your lookup method is abstract it will implement otherwise override.When you call the lookup method it will call the Proxy class method, and it will give the every time new Object.